# PowerShell DSC Local Configuration Manager and mixed Configuration Modes

Tags: powershell, dsc, lcm

I”m evaluating DSC, and I have a question about the LCM. I understand that I can use mixedmode with pull/push scenarios, but what about the ConfigurationMode setting for the LCM?

I have a situation where the LCM could be set to ApplyandAutoCorrect but I need to apply partial configurations where the configuration would be set to ApplyOnly. I don’t want the LCM to monitor this particular change.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently DSC doesn't support ConfigurationMode per partial configuration. There is a uservoice item for the same @ https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/12251481-set-configurationmode-per-partialconfiguration. Please vote on uservoice.